# solr displayed some results first when they are part of the results

Tags: solr

I consider this solr psedo-doc

```
<doc>
<field name="title"/>
<field name="name"/>
<field name="keywords"/>
</doc>
```

Some **doc's will have the keyword "up"** which means that they should appear first (despite of their initial order position) when and only when **they are part** of the search results.

**So lets say I have:**

```
doc1('title1','Bob, Alice','people, up, couple')
doc2('title2','Smart Phone, Laptop, Bob','devices, electronics')
```

if I query with "**title:title2 name:Bob**" then I should get doc1 first (it has the 'up' keyword). 
if I query with "**name:Bob**" I still get doc1 first for the same reason.
if I query with "**name:Laptop**" then I should only get doc2 in my results. doc1 should not be included since it doesnt match my search query.

Any suggestion to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options to do something like that:

- function query / boost query (in dismax handler)
- during index time (boost documents)
- extract 'up' keyword to additional field and sort by this field, than score

For example (with dismax handler):

```
 /select?defType=dismax&q=...&bq=keywords:"up"^1000
```

Comment: I can only query not modify the index. an example please?

Comment: If you can use dismax try something like:
/select?defType=dismax&q=...&bq=keywords:"up"^1000

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with Solr's query time boosting. So following the guidance from the [Solr Relevancy FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_make_.22superman.22_in_the_title_field_score_higher_than_in_the_subject_field) - you could add an additional boosted search term to all queries, e.g. `title:title2 name:Bob keywords:up^2`

You could also at index time for each document, determine if the up keyword is present then store that in an additional field (boolean for example) in your schema and boost the query results based on that boolean field.

Comment: your first suggestion isnt going to work because in every search I have to append the keywords:up^2 so when I search with title:title10 keywords:up^2 - I will get one result despite the fact that I shouldn't

Comment: Ok, then you will need to go the second route and store the additional field that you can boost on at query time.